# Question on plotting in Python closed very quickly

Tags: discussion, on-topic, closing-questions, software, reopen-closed

I have just noticed this question:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243679/how-can-i-make-seaborn-plot-the-null-values

The question have 9 views, and it is already voted to be closed by 5 users.

That means, that the OP + me + 5 "close voters" = 7, basically the question had only 2 silent users actually viewed the question.

I would advice to reopen the question, and give it a chance, since it is not off-topic, and there is enough info in it to answer.

Comment: Why do you say it's not off-topic? - what's the statistical aspect of the question? It does *seem* to be just a coding question.

Comment: `seaborn` is used to visualize your results, same as `ggplot` in `R`.

Comment: Thus, it as "off-topic" as all of these results : http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ggplot

Comment: Well, many of the posts returned by your search have indeed been closed for being off-topic. Many merely illustrate something using  `ggplot`, without being *about* it. Others have a statistical aspect to them, & others were posted when our site policy was different. I'd imagine you could find *some* recent ones that are just coding questions if you looked, just as you could find some unclear or overly broad questions. The help page says "if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here" - else SO or ...

Comment: ... [one of these sites](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/793/17230) is appropriate. This one will be fine for SO, I think, if a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is added.

Comment: @amoeba: You'll notice some are already locked: "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed." Others should be closed for other reasons - e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/209407/17230, which the OP never made clear enough for us to tell if there was a statistical issue in there.

Comment: Seriously? there is a tag `ggplot2`, that is very active, with almost exclusively visualization related questions

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ggplot2

Comment: I can't see why visualization questions by `python` users who are using `matplotlib` or `seaborn` should be off topic in `cross-validated`

Comment: The general policy is set out here http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (see **Programming**).

Comment: "data visualization" is listed there, whether you consider "data visualization tools" as "on-topic" or  "off-topic" is not my concern. However you should be consistent with `R` tools as well as `python` tools, and this is clearly not the case.

Comment: That's the policy. It's hard to answer an assertion based on a personal impression that it's not being followed consistently  I can assure you from personal experience that many people with voting powers try to follow it. I have very often voted to close R-focused questions as off-topic.

Comment: Not your question, but the original question is unclear any way: where on a box plot do missing values belong???

Answer (score 10):

Contrary to your [comment](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/question-closed-very-quickly#comment11266_4426), questions that are *only* about how to use `R` (e.g., `ggplot2`) are off topic here, whether for visualization or analysis or other purposes, and are regularly closed as such.  The same is true for questions that are only about how to use `Python` (e.g., `seaborn`, `matplotlib`, etc.), `Stata`, `Minitab`, `SAS`, etc.  A question such as, 'should I use barplots or boxplots for these data' is about *data visualization*, and is on topic here.  A question like 'how to I make a barplot in seaborn' is not about data visualization, it is about *how to use seaborn*.  Such questions can be on topic on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and regularly get good answers there.

I think this policy is applied consistently across software.  Examine the questions listed under the [ggplot2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ggplot2) tag.  When viewed in the **newest** tab, you will see that all of the most recent 8 questions have been closed.  But what about a question like: [Visualizing highly dimensional data with response that can take only 3 values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/235367/7290), which is tagged with [ggplot2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ggplot2) and wasn't closed?  If you look at the thread, you will see the question reads,

> I fail to think of a good way to visualize these data. I would like to visualize the space formed by the explanatory variables a,b,c,e,f and see which combinations is causing the the y variable to take one value or another.

That is a question about how to visualize data; `ggplot2` is simply the OP's preferred software.  But the OP may not get an answer to that part, and it is part of the social contract here that that is OK.  (In fact, neither of the two answers include `ggplot2` code; the one that has plots were made with `JMP`.)  This example provides another way to think about this issue:

1. If a question could be well answered using other software, it is probably on topic here.
2. If the answer doesn't matter, but only the code demonstrating the plot does, and it must use the same software, then the question is about the software, not the plot or the data.  It is off topic on CV, but may well be on topic elsewhere (like SO).

---

As a technical detail, almost certainly the close votes were applied from the review queue.  The views of the thread in the review queue do not count towards the views enumerated on the thread.